# Connecting a UILabel to Maps

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview with cells containing addresses and I want the user to be able to tap on the address (which is a UILabel) and then be directed to that location in Apple's Maps app.

Since locations are in an array, I don't know how I can parse through that array so that each location in each cell has the ability to (when tapped on)go to its location on Apple Maps.

UPDATE: Code is working now, the solution is present below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class FirstEventCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var eventLocation: UILabel! 

 @IBAction func goToMaps(_ sender: UIButton) {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString((eventLocation?.text)!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("")
        } else if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            let location = placemark.location
            let coords = location!.coordinate
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coords.latitude,coords.longitude)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
            mapItem.name = "Target location"
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])

        }
    })
}

}


class EventsTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var locations = ["Washington, DC 20565", "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW,  Washington, DC 20500", "East Capitol St NE & First St SE, Washington, DC 20004"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locations.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)

    let eventLocation = locations[indexPath.row]

    if let eventCell = cell as? FirstEventCell {
        eventCell.eventLocation.text = eventLocation
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I assume you know how to define didSelectRowAtIndexPath? I'm not sure whether this is a question about UITableView, or converting an address into a CLLocation for your MKMapView.

Comment: @dylanthelion's is a common way to do if not the only one. If have more than one table, they both will generate calls to the function so you have to be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: @curt: You probably know this, but the correct way to handle multiple tables on the same view, is to have multiple UITableViewDelegates and UITableViewDataSources.

Comment: @dylanthelion It's about converting an address into a CLLocation for MKMapView so that when the user taps on the address, iOS jumps to the maps app to that location.

Comment: Okay. I've done that before. You're gonna need a Geocoder, which is a bit obnoxious, but I'll try and find you the last code I used, and give you an answer. @ParankushBhardwaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is months old (pre-Swift 3.0), and part of a project that needs updating, so please tell me if it does not work, and I'll work on fixing it for you. The things you need to know: 'self' is a UIViewController, 'AddressTextField' is a UITextField, into which an address is entered, and is a property of the ViewController (via IBOutlet), 'pm' is a CLPLacemark, and 'address' is a CLLocation:

```
CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(self.AddressTextField.text!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0]
                let address = pm.location!
            }
        })
```

Put something similar in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath, after using indexPath.row to get the address as a String, and put that address in place of 'self.AddressTextField.text!'. If it works, you can use the 'address' CLLocation variable, to build an MKMapView.

Comment: It turns out that I just had to create an invisible button on top of the address label, and whenever its clicked, it just grabs the text of the cell and then converts the string to coordinates, and then uses the coordinates to open up the location in Maps. Strange way to do it, but surprisingly effective.